# How do I use attribute in formatted string?

Tags: python, string

When I use it like this, it works fine:

```
print(f'The current price is: {get_price}')
```

But not like this (and I want the price, not the whole "**get_price**"):

```
print(f'The current price is: {get_price['price']}')
```

Error:

```
print(f'The current price is: {get_price['price']}')
                                              ^
SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['
```

What is the proper way?

Comment: Python doesn't understand that you have nested quotes. Just use different quotes for the two purposes: `print(f"The current price is: {get_price['price']}")`

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Could you answer so I can select your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not formatted strings themselves, its the characters you're using. You cannot make a string `'My name is 'Jack' '` because of the ' characters terminating the string prematurly. F-strings are still strings and will experence the same problem. For this, you would use the double quote. Dothis `'My name is "Jack" '`